# Input/output error using fit_generator in Keras

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, large-data

I have a large training matrix storing images and corresponding classes in h5 format. I want to read the images and their labels for training a model in Keras. Since the dataset is too large, I created my own data generator function *imageLoader()* and used it in *model.fit_generator*. The *imageLoader()* reads the training data in batches of size *batch_size* and use it for training.

The training matrix (h5 file) contains data as follows:

Train_features: (58160 x 25 x 25 x 50) => no. of images x row x col x channels

Train_class: (58160 x 1) => no. of images x label

However, I am still getting memory error when using fit_generator in Keras. Following is my code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(7)  
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Activation
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
import h5py


h5f = h5py.File('path to h5 file', 'r')

#Data Generator
def imageLoader(h5f, batch_size):
    L= len(h5f['train_class'])
    while True:
        batch_start=0
        batch_end= batch_size
        while batch_start<L:
            limit = min(batch_end, L)
            X= h5f['train_features'][batch_start:limit]
            Y= h5f['train_class'][batch_start:limit]
            print(batch_start, batch_end)

            yield (X,keras.utils.to_categorical(Y,2)) #I have two classes

            batch_start +=batch_size
            batch_end +=batch_size

# Building Model
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(80,(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape= (25,25,50)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(150,(4,4), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(200,(4,4), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
model.summary()


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = 
['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(imageLoader(h5f,100), 
steps_per_epoch=len(h5f['train_class'])/100, epochs=3)
```

Here is the error log:

```
Epoch 1/3
0 100
100 200
200 300
300 400
400 500
500 600
600 700
700 800
800 900
900 1000
1000 1100
1/54 [..............................] - ETA: 22s - loss: 0.9183 - acc: 
0.11001100 1200
1200 1300
1300 1400
1400 1500
5/54 [=>............................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.9579 - acc: 0.0380 
1500 1600
7/54 [==>...........................] - ETA: 42s - loss: 0.8970 - acc: 
0.1429
Exception in thread Thread-28:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
 self.run()
 File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3- 4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", 
line 579, in data_generator_task
generator_output = next(self._generator)
  File "<ipython-input-119-7a1d852e803c>", line 10, in imageLoader
    X= h5f['test_features'][batch_start:limit]
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 496, in __getitem__
self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 181, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 130, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 84, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread
OSError: Can't read data (file read failed: time = Wed Oct  3 23:43:01 2018
, filename = '/mnt/hdd/shreya/change_detection_files/san_test_data.h5', file 
descriptor = 86, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 
0x7f53b2990c80, total read size = 6415424, bytes this sub-read = 6415424, 
bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 418586624)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-120-e74f6fee0af9>", line 15, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(imageLoader(h5f,100), 
steps_per_epoch=len(h5f['test_class'])/100, epochs=3)

  File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1156, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/saror/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/envs/py3dl2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2046, in fit_generator
generator_output = next(output_generator)

StopIteration
```

Could anyone please tell what is wrong in the above code? How can I read large data efficiently for model training?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in stacktrace there is `X= h5f['test_features'][batch_start:limit]` but in code you have `X= h5f['train_features'][batch_start:limit]`. are you sure you put rigth stacktrace here?